# Adaptive Mutex in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-2.7, concurrency

Does anyone know how to write a Hybrid mutex in python?

By Hybrid Mutex I mean a mutex that does both: it spins for a time in anticipation of a quick lock, but eventually blocks the thread if things take too long, relinquishing the CPU.

I know that people have given it a try in C but am looking for a pythonic way to do it. 
For eg: https://hackernoon.com/building-a-c-hybrid-spin-mutex-f98de535b4ac

Answer (score 0):

```
class hybridSpinLock:
def __init__(self):
    self.lock_var = threading.Lock()
    self.threshold = 1
def lock(self):
    #stalling
    start = time.time()
    elapsed = 0
    while (self.lock_var.acquire(False)==False):
        elapsed = time.time() - start
        if elapsed >= 2*self.threshold:
            self.lock_var.acquire()  # blocking lock
            break
    #update the threshold value
    self.threshold += (elapsed - self.threshold)/8
def release(self):
    self.threshold=1
    self.lock_var.release()
```